# Perform href before window.location.reload();

Tags: javascript

I have a function that reloads the page on button click, but I want the href to be performed first, but right now it just refreshes and doesn't go to the new page

```
 <a onclick="ReloadPage()" href=menu.html#Pizza>Pizza</a>

function ReloadPage()
{
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt mix these two functions together as the onclick function will always execute first.

Comment: Try  `setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you refresh the page anyway on href change, you will not get another refresh after navigated away from the page.
After you refreshed you don't have control anymore of what will be executed.
If you really need it, You can use session storage or query variables for persistent data sharing.